# Form validation with JS not working

Tags: javascript, html

**HTML**

```
<form name="suggestion" method="post" action="suggestion.php"              
    class="elegant-aero" onSubmit="return validate()" >                 
    <label>
    <span>Message :</span>
    <textarea id="Message" name="message" placeholder="Your Message to Us"></textarea>
    </label>
    <input type="submit" class="buttonc" value="SEND" onclick="validate()">
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function validate() {
    var message = document.suggestion.message.value;
    if (message == "") {
        alert("Message box should not be leaved empty");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? My validate function is not working. Please give me some suggestion.

Comment: For what input happens what? And what should happen instead?

Comment: Also, why are you calling validate() both onclick and onsubmit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access a form by names, you have to do this:

```
var message = document.forms["suggestion"].elements["message"].value;
```

But better is to do it with an **ID**.

---

**BUT**

the easiest way to do, what you want, is to set the required attribute in `<textarea>`

```
<textarea required>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the main error lies in that `document.suggestion.message.value` is not a valid selector from my understanding. Try [`getElementById`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp) to get that form selected.

Comment: It is a valid selector we can do this while dealing with forms

Answer (score 0):

Code is good, but you must correctly place script in document

Look here 
http://jsfiddle.net/wLrg26s0/4/
On left side of jsbin is selected `no wrap - in <body>` its mean that code look like

```
<body>
   <!-- page -->
   <script>
      //js here
   </script>
<body>
```

Function declare this way go to `window` name space. Its global name space, and there `onSubmit` search for `validate` function.

If you select on left side of jsbin `onLoad` then code looks like (and don't forget to click run)

```
   <script>
      $( document ).ready(function() {
        //js here
      });
   </script>
```

And script not work, because function is declared somewhere else.
To fix this you must declare function in this way

```
window.validate = function(){ /*code */}
```

Comment: i did by selecting onLoad but the script works fine too for this